# Twilio API get DateSent from StatusCallback URL?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am using Twilio and I want to get the DateSent parameter of a message. When the message is initially sent it has `null` values for both `DateCreated` and `DateSent`. So I pass a StatusCallback URL to receive any status updates on that message. However, I am able to get only the new statuses the message gets such as `sent`, or `delivered` and not the new date as an event. In the docs I couldn't find anything about this either (https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages#monitor-the-status-of-your-message). What is the way to get this information without continuously polling the API?

Answer (score 0):

The date created is included as part of the response from the API. If you find that is not the case can you please post example code.
When the sms is actually sent you can pull the message resource using the api or sdk via the sid https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#fetch-a-message-resource

Comment: I pass a `StatusCallback` URL, but the only events that I receive there are the ones where the message's send status changes. But that's all in the request body. No info whatsoever about the new date of the event or so. I can, of course, add it manually as `Date.now()` and do the things I need to do with it but I was thinking if there is a better way.

Comment: @DavidPrifti i misunderstood your question , I modified my answer

Comment: I read your updated answer. However, that would end up making API calls for every new message sent. It would be great if the `DateSent` information came in the request of the status callback, but seems like it's not possible.